# SharePoint Server Error Logs at AnalyticsProcessingComponent

Tags: search, 2016, server-farm, uls, server

While Monitoring ULS logs for the below server configurations,

2 SharePoint 2016 Application server each with 
Windows Server 2012 R2 (64bit)
32 GB of RAM
May 2016 CU updated.
2.10 GHz (2 Processors)

Any Idea what need to be done?

```
Microsoft.Ceres.CoreServices.Node.NodeController : Error during Node Constellation for AnalyticsProcessingComponent1 Microsoft.Ceres.CoreServices.Framework.Messages.MessageHandlingException: No primary system manager available    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.CoreServices.Node.NodeController.GetSystemManager(Int32 timeout)    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.CoreServices.Node.NodeController.ConstellateThread.ConstellatePoll()    
 at Microsoft.Ceres.CoreServices.Node.NodeController.ConstellateThread.DoWorkIteration()
```